# mediastream not displaying in browser, although browser seems to access camera

Tags: javascript, video, browser, webrtc, mediadevices

I have an issue trying to display my local camera in a HTML/.ejs page.  My code seems to be functional, however the video is not displaying in the 'video tag' element on the page.  The strange thing is the browser (Chrome) is indicating to me the camera and microphone are being accessed (with the little camera icon and 'dot' in the browser tab).  What am I doing wrong here?  Any help greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

Here is the HTML/EJS:

```
<!-- views/pages/about.ejs -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<% include ../partials/head %>

<title>Realtime communication with WebRTC</title>

 <style type="text/css">
   #localVideo {
       height:225px;
       width:300px;
       float:left;
       border:1px solid gray;
       margin-left:10px;
   }
   #remoteVideo {
       height:225px;
       width:300px;
       border:1px solid gray;
       margin-left:10px;
   }
   div.local {
   border:5px red;
   }
</style>

</head>

<body class="container">

<header>
<% include ../partials/header %>
</header>

<main>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-6">        
    <div class="remote">
     <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>

     <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-7">    
    <div class="local">

       <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>

      <input type = "text" id = "otherUsernameInput" />
      <button id = "connectToOtherUsernameBtn">Establish connection</button> 

      <div>
       <button id="startButton">Start</button>
       <button id="callButton">Call</button>
       <button id="hangupButton">Hang Up</button>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>

</div>

<p id="demo"> This is some text in a paragraph. </p>

</main>

<footer>
<% include ../partials/footer %>
</footer>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/js/my_main.js"></script>

    <script>

        document.getElementById("callButton").disabled = true;

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

         // A dialog box is displayed when the server sends us a "message"
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            alert('The server has a message for you: ' + message);
        })

        connectToOtherUsernameBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){ 

        var username = document.getElementById("otherUsernameInput").value; 

        //it's sent with the signal "lucky_hit" (to differentiate it from "message")
        socket.emit('lucky_hit', username);

        socket.emit('message', 'Hi server, how are you?');

        });

       startButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ 

       socket.emit('start_me_up', 'Requesting Local Video...');

       });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the "my_main.js" script which just accesses and (should) play the local camera video:

```
startButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
console.log("Start Pressed"); 
document.getElementById("startButton").innerHTML = "Play Video";


// Prefer camera resolution nearest to 1280x720.
var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } };     

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

 if (!navigator.getuserMedia) {
 console.log('You are using a browser that does not support the Media Capture API');
 return;  //end script execution with an empty return... 
 }  //navigator.getuserMedia NOT returned...

}  //handle older browsers that may not fully support mediaDevices...


navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
 var video = document.querySelector('localVideo');

 video.srcObject = mediaStream;
 //  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
 video.play();
 //   console.log('Video META data loaded...')
 //  };
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });  //always check for errors at the end.

});
```

As previously mentioned the camera/microphone appear to be accessed by the browser, and I do not get any error messages.  Thank you for any insight.  Regards.

Comment: Do you use SSL encryption?

Comment: Not at this time...however it should display anyway since I am using 'localhost'...therefore the lack of SSL/HTTPS should not be an issue.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hello @Pangit my bad I thought that there are two id's with same name I've deleted my answer

Comment: OK no problem, thanks for the response anyway.